# Combining 2 square matrices into another square matrix with all elements in R

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to combine two square matrices of differing dimensions into one square matrix whose dimensions are the sum of the original two. I have one matrix that's 392 x 392 and another that's 497 x 497. What I want is a 3rd that's 889 x 889.

As an example, if I had matrix a and matrix b as described below:

```
a <- matrix(sample(0:1, 25, replace=T), nrow=5, ncol=5)
b <- matrix(rep(0,16 ), nrow=4, ncol=4)
rownames(a) <- letters[1:5]
colnames(a) <- letters[1:5]
rownames(b) <- letters[6:9]
colnames(b) <- letters[6:9]
```

How would I get to matrix c that looks like this:

```
{c <- matrix(c(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), nrow=10,ncol=10)
```

I've tried cbindX from the gdata package as well as some other solutions from this site, but nothing is working. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: *"I have one matrix that's 392 x 392 and another that's 497 x 497. What I want is a 3rd that's 889 x 889"* Uh, what? I don't understand how you want to achieve that. You can either column-bind or row-bind entries, provided the dimensions match. Can you clarify with a minimal example?

Comment: Not clear enough... Do you want to put the two square matrices in the diagonal and then zeros around?

Comment: Oops, apologies, I hit post before making a reproducible example. I will fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I really understood the problem...
Use this:

```
C <- Matrix::bdiag(a, b) %>% 
        as.matrix
```

This command will create a *block diagonal matrix*.

Comment: This is perfect, except is there a way that I can preserve the column and row names? Edit: Nevermind, I figured out a workaround.

Comment: I'm glad that helped! :D